# Magento 2 : Marketplace issue combine swatch-renderer js for 2.3 and 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, marketplace, requirejs-config.js

> I have two different modules for 2.3 and 2.4 which is using mixin js, I want both these modules to be compatible in one to submit in the marketplace

```
 map: {
        '*': {
            'mymodule/configurableproducts': 'Myvendor_Mymodule/js/configproducts',
        },
    },
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box': {
            'Myvendor_Mymodule/js/price-box': true
        }
    },
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
            'Myvendor_Mymodule/js/swatch-renderer-mixin': true
        }
    }
}
```

**Please let me know if anyone has any idea.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Finally, I figured it out by myself. There is a file at
> `Myvendor/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml`
>
> In this file, there are variables that are passing to the js file so I
> added version check variable as below.

```
$objManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$magentoVersion = $objManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface');
$replace = [".", "-"]; // for p1/p2 version
$versionCheck = json_encode(str_replace($replace, "", $magentoVersion->getVersion()));

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#module-ptd-table": {
                "mymodule/configurableproducts": {
                    "jsonChildInfo": <?php echo $block->jsonChildInfo(); ?>,
                    "versionCheck": <?php echo $versionCheck; ?>
                 }
            },

            "[data-role=swatch-options]": {
                "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer": {
                    "attributeCount": <?php echo $block->attributesCount(); ?>,
                    "jsonConfig": <?php echo $swatchOptions = $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>,
                    "jsonSwatchConfig": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo $swatchOptions = $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
                    "mediaCallback": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getMediaCallback())) ?>",
                    "isEnableExtension": true,
                    "versionCheck": <?php echo $versionCheck; ?>
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**I am able to get variable in js file as followed.**

```
const regEx = /^24/;
if (regEx.test(this.options.versionCheck)) {
// for 2.4 code
}else{
// for 2.3 code 
}
```

**As I wanted this package to work in 2.3 and 2.4 and it worked for me, cheers ;).**